# Event System: How to know if editor clicked Save or Save & Close?

Tags: tridion

In Tridion 2011 SP1 I'm trying to implement an event that will publish items automatically whenever the editor presses Save & Close (but not Save).

Under normal conditions this could be handled in a CheckIn event, but because this item will probably be in workflow, there is no CheckIn event (yet).

In COM Events we had a flag (doneEditing) to tell us if the editor had pressed save & close vs Save. I don't seem to be able to find a similar option in TOM.NET Events.

For reference - here's the code so far:

```cs
[TcmExtension("Publish to Wip Events")]
public class PublishToWip : TcmExtension
{
    public PublishToWip()
    {
        EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<VersionedItem, SaveEventArgs>(PublishItemToWip, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
    }
    private void PublishItemToWip(VersionedItem item, SaveEventArgs args, EventPhases phases)
    {
       // Magic goes here
    }
}
```

I've looked at the options for SaveEventArgs, but haven't found anything that would provide me this information. Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, with some help from the CM team I got the right answer to this.

Use the CheckInEvent instead of save. Even if the item is in workflow it will still invoke this event when you click Save & Close (and **only** if you click Save & Close, not when you click Save).

Something like this will get me going:

```cs
[TcmExtension("Publish to Wip Events")]
public class PublishToWip : TcmExtension
{
    public PublishToWip()
    {
        EventSystem.Subscribe<VersionedItem, CheckInEventArgs>
            (PublishItemToWip, EventPhases.Processed);
    }
    private void PublishItemToWip(VersionedItem item, 
        CheckInEventArgs args, EventPhases phases)
    {

        if (!item.LockType.HasFlag(LockType.InWorkflow)) return;

        if (!item.IsCheckedOut) return;
        // do something now
```

Comment: Instead of the Processed phase you will probably want to use the TransactionCommitted phase for this CheckIn event. That way you are sure the save and close action actually finished and did not encounter an error somewhere in its process. This is also what I described in the event matrix in my Event System article on SDL Tridion World http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/sdltridion2011eventsystem.aspx

Comment: I'll give it a try on TransactionCommitted. Not sure it will work because the CheckIn never actually happens - the item is in workflow.

Comment: Yeah that's the one thing I indeed don't think I considered when I write the old to new matrix. Would be interested to hear if the transaction does commit or not.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at this in the past, but I couldn't find a suitable solution. In the end I gave up.

The idea I had was to have a GUI extension to intercept the Save and as such write an AppData entry for that item saying it was a Save or a SaveClose. Then your event system would read the AppData and act accordingly.

Don't forget to clean up the AppData in your event code.

Comment: Indeed, there seems to be absolutely nothing different in the event... If there is no workflow, the CheckInAfterSave flag is probably set to true - but in that scenario I would execute my code in the CheckIn event anyway...

Comment: The CheckInAfterSave flag would in that case only be set to true if the item was automatically checked out when you started editing. If you first check out the item (e.g. from the context menu) and then open it for editing, closing the dialog with Save-and-close won't check in the item. Explicit check out -> explicit check in.

Answer (score -1):

In order to catch item finished workflow you need to subscribe to FinishProcess event on the Process, not on the component:

```
EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<Process, FinishProcessEventArgs>(FinishProcessHandler, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted, EventSubscriptionOrder.Late);
```

In the event handler Process instance will contain list of Subjects with the versioned item finished workflow - the one you want to publish:

```
private static void FinishProcessHandler(Process process, FinishProcessEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
{
   foreach (var itemInWorkflow in process.Subjects)
   {
      //publish
   }
}
```

Comment: Nuno is not looking for a finished workflow, he is looking for whether the user clicked Save-and-close.